# Video Gallery using ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-videoview

I am creating a gallery app to show and slide through different media (videos and pictures). The issue is when i have videos adjacent to each other. If i slide the video keeps on playing and doesn't stop.

I am implementing `ViewPager` in an `Activity` without a `Fragment`. I extend `PagerAdapter` from my custom adapter. Apparently in fragments the solution is to override this method:

`void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)`

However, how can i achieve this functionality without using fragments with my `ViewPager`

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

<del>You can't.</del> Apparently you can use a ViewPager without fragments, but it requires you to add code complexity that I don't see you needing since you already have [FragmentPagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) and [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html). ViewPager is designed to keep views "alive" so they don't have to be redrawn on a swipe event. I can think of several ways to solve your issue:

1. Use a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` because your use case appears to be suited for it (read the docs).
2. Set your viewPager instance with `setOffscreenPageLimit(1)`, although it seems that 1 is the default setting.
3. Implement `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` in your activity, and when a fragment is not visible anymore stop the video yourself.